# JQuery append from array overwrites table rows

Tags: jquery, append

I am sorting a table in JQuery by putting the rows into an array and then sorting the array which works fine. 
This code to add the sorted array to the table works but why does the append in this code,

```
    $.each(arrData, function (index, row) {
      $('tbody').append(row);
    });
```

overwrite the existing rows rather than adding to the end of the table ?

Comment: Your code wroks fine! See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ebLc1zxs/2/

Comment: `append()` does not inheriently ovewrite anything.  As it is named, it appends elements.  If you are seeing behavior that is undesired, or seems to contradict this, you need to make a [mcve] to show us your issue

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/ *You can select an element on the page and insert it into another - if an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)*

Comment: So, because the rows in the array are already on the page they are moved into the table, row 1 in the array is moved into row 1 in the table, row 2 in the array into row 2 of the table and so on ?